# CSS issue with background grey causing blue button to have white contour

Tags: html, css

[image: picture of both buttons demonstrating the white space]

As the image demonstrates my buttons labelled New Task, and New Note are completely fine but Submit and Cancel because of the grey background have some weird white shadow shading?

So my guess is that my buttons blue colouring in combination with the styling in the background must be causing an issue?

below: CSS styling for the buttons on the screen (there is no JS affecting this page yet), and the HTML is very basic.

```
.btn {
    background: #3498db;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
    -webkit-border-radius: 28;
    -moz-border-radius: 28;
    border-radius: 28px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline-color: #808080;
    font-family:Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
}

.btn:hover {
    background: #3cb0fd;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: have u tried .btn { border-style: none; } ?

Comment: @rickjancawaling Wow it worked I'm so stupid. Thank you for the quick response, do you suggest I close the question?

Comment: i will post it as an answer and can you check it? :)

Comment: @rickjancawaling sure thing go ahead and post, you were first. Most deserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting border-style: none

**YOUR CODE**

```
.btn {
    border-style: none; // just add this one :)
    background: #3498db;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
    -webkit-border-radius: 28;
    -moz-border-radius: 28;
    border-radius: 28px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline-color: #808080;
    font-family:Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
}

.btn:hover {
    background: #3cb0fd;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following CSS to your existing `.button` class. It is a border causing problem to the default buttons.

```
.btn {
  border:none;
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either change or remove the default `border` from your buttons.

```
.btn {
    background: #3498db;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
    -webkit-border-radius: 28;
    -moz-border-radius: 28;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 28px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline-color: #808080;
    font-family:Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `border: none;` to `.btn` class here i have updated css try this

```css
.btn {
    border: none;
    background: #3498db;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
    -webkit-border-radius: 28;
    -moz-border-radius: 28;
    border-radius: 28px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline-color: #808080;
    font-family:Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```